# Upload Csv to solution explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, filestream

I'm trying to build an application in which a user can upload a csv file and convert it into XML. Currently my controller can create .txt file in a temp folder. However when I open the txt file it comes out all corrupted as below:
[image: Upload]

I have two questions
1. How can I make it so that the file displays properly i.e. as items separated by commas?
2. How can I change my code to make the file upload into my solution explorer

Here is the relevant controller code:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var filePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if(formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                var filePath = Path.GetTempPath()+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".txt";
                filePaths.Add(filePath);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePaths });
    }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a binary file, not a CSV. A CSV is just *text* with specific delimiters. The `FileUpload` method doesn't perform any kind of conversion, it just saves the uploaded files.

Comment: I suspect this is actually an Excel file. The `xlsx` format used by Excel is a zip package that contains XML files. `Content_Types.xml` is one of the standard files. Use a library like Epplus to read it.

Comment: You should check each file's `ContentType` property and possibly the extension too. Don't append `.txt` unless you're sure it's a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file is corrupt I think the conversion doesn't work. Try for now uploading it without any conversion.

For the second question you can do the following

```cs
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.csv"); // or whatever extension you are actually having without modifying the original extension
```

This will store the file either in the "bin" directory path or in the directory where the source-code is located.